# How to stop Excel from mangling a formula inserted by my VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script in an Excel workbook that gathers results from all the workbooks in a particular folder.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim path As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim data As Object

    Set data = Worksheets("RawData")
    path = data.Range("A1").Value

    i = 3

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)   

    data.Rows("2:" & data.Rows.Count).ClearContents

    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Right(UCase(file.name), 5) = ".XLSX" And Left(file.name, 1) <> "~" Then
            data.Cells(i, 2) = "='" + path + "\[" + file.name + "]Summary'!A1:J1"
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next file

End Sub
```

The idea is for each `.xlsx` file in a given folder, I add a reference to the results range in that file. For example, if there is a file `Test1.xlsx` in folder `C:\Sheets`, the VBA puts the following formula into some row on the sheet containing the script:

```
='C:\Sheets\[Test1.xlsx]Summary'!A1:J1
```

Excel then pulls values out of `Test1` and puts them in the current workbook's `RawData` sheet.

This worked until today, when my formulas started ending up with `@` right after the `=` sign, like this:

```
=@'C:\Sheets\[Test1.xlsx]Summary'!A1:J1
```

This gives me a `#VALUE?`.

Excel helpfully gave me a message stating that it has just now started inserting `@` into formulas due to some syntax changes, but that it wouldn't affect calculations. I can't get this message to show up again, but that was the gist of it. Obviously it does affect calculations. If I manually remove the `@` from the formula, it works fine.

I have Office 365 and I guess I must have received an update recently that added this "feature" because all this used to work fine.

If I modify the VBA script to reference only a single cell, the `@` does not get inserted. But using a named range for the results (rather than `A1:J1`) still has the problem.

Anyone have any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: `data.Cells(i, 2).Formula` might be a better approach if you're assigning a formula

Comment: IIRC, to avoid the `@` from being inserted, use the `.Formula2` property of the range object.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld If you post that as an answer, I'll select it. (It worked!)

Comment: @kindall glad to help. Answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the `@` from being inserted, use the `.Formula2` property of the range object.
This change has to do with the dynamic array feature of Excel O365

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the formula to a variable and then remove the `@` from the string using the `Right()` function...

As the length of the string will be dynamic depending on the length of the file name, I've used the `Len()` function to get the full lenght of the string, then minus 2 from it to remove the `=` and `@`.

Note the `=` is concatenated with the `Right()` function when assigning the value to the cell.

```
Dim FormulaString as String
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Right(UCase(file.name), 5) = ".XLSX" And Left(file.name, 1) <> "~" Then
            FormulaString = "='" + path + "\[" + file.name + "]Summary'!A1:J1"
            data.Cells(i, 2) = "=" & Right(FormulaString, Len(FormulaString) - 2)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next file
```

---

Output is

```
='C:\Sheets\[Test1.xlsx]Summary'!A1:J1
```